# Passing file name as an argument in C

Tags: c

I got stuck on a problem that I can't figure out. For my task I have to do some work with .txt files in C, and in specific, I have to pass file names using command line parameters. Let's say we have this part of the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){


FILE *ptr_fd;
ptr_fd = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

The part that confuses me is how do you work with these arguments ? Where do you place your .txt file ? I've read a hundred threads but I still can't wrap my head around it. I'm using XCode and am working on a Mac. Do I have to use Terminal in any way to work with this code ? Any shed of light on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are not familiar at all with the Terminal and command line usage? But it should be possible to provide a command line inside XCode as well.

Comment: No. Up until now I simply always used the Xcode compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCode, you can specify the arguments to be passed to your program in the scheme. Go to Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme and switch to the "Arguments" tab (see screenshot).

Any file is then loaded from where XCode places the executable. The easiest way to find out where this is is to right-click on the product and "show in finder" (see screenshot).

Outside of XCode, e.g. in a terminal window, simply specify parameters after the command name, e.g. `./testCommandLine test.txt`. Any file open will - if no absolute path is given - start the lookup from the current working directory.

Hope it helps.

[image: Edit current scheme]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If given a relative file path, `fopen` will open files relative to current working directory.  If you pass an absolute path to you program, then `fopen` will use that.  For example, if your `file.txt` is located in `/home/User/file.txt`, you can pass that entire string to your program and `fopen` will find it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is to check that you've got a parameter.

```
if(argc!=2){printf("Usage:...");exit(1);}
```

After that, you can use the parameter(s) directly. Note that `argv[0]` will be the path/name of the executable, `argv[1]` will be the first parameter (if passed), and so on. When opening files, they must be either placed in the working directory, or you have to pass `fopen` a path in addition to the filename. The working directory may or may not be the directory containing your executable, depending on your build environment.